# How to save each line in a text file as new file

Tags: awk, while-loop

I have a tab delimited text file with 5 columns, and I'd like each row to be its own txt file that contains information from columns 2-5 and is named after column 1.

For example, my txt file has hundreds of rows similar to this:

sample1name_oligos  primer  forwardseq  reverseseq  sample1name

sample2name_oligos  primer  forwardseq  reverseseq  sample2name

I'd like to have a txt file named sample1name_oligos that look like this:

primer  forwardseq  reverseseq  sample1name

and a txt file named sample1name_oligos that looks like this:

primer  forwardseq  reverseseq  sample1name

I've tried two ways:

## 1. I found what I thought was the solution:

awk '{print substr($0,match($0,$2)) >> ( $1 ".txt" )}' filename

(from http://www.linuxquestions.org/questions/linux-newbie-8/how-to-save-each-line-from-textfile-as-new-file-889795/)

This worked for the test file I made (5 rows), but when I run it on my 100+ rows file I get the first 17 files out and then the error:

awk: File18.txt makes too many open files
input record number 18, file myfile.txt
source line number 1

I deleted row 18 and retried and got the same error. I deleted the first 20 lines and retried and got the same error.

## 2. From the same link, I tried

cat myfile.txt | while read LINE; do echo $LINE > "$LINE.txt"; done.

This made a file for each row that looked like this:

sample1name_oligos  primer  forwardseq  reverseseq  sample1name

and the file was named:

sample1name_oligos  primer  forwardseq  reverseseq  sample1name.

I'm not sure where to go from here. I'd appreciate any help. If it's not obvious, I have little Terminal experience so I'd also appreciate answers that explain what I'm missing.

Bonnie

Comment: In your awk you have to `close( $1 ".txt" )` the file when finished writing (after each row in your case).  This is indicated by the `too many open files` error.

Comment: @n0741337 ... or use GNU awk which simply handles that for you as needed.

Comment: @Bonnie In my test, `awk '{print substr($0,match($0,$2)) >> ( $1 ".txt" )}' filename` works just fine with 100+ rows. Do check whether there is additional WHITE SPACE in the 1st field of the questionable lines, which makes duplicated file names for output.

Comment: @xb this has nothing to do with the file contents, it's a concurrently open files issue with the awk the OP is using.

Comment: @Bonnie never do `substr($0,match($0,$2))` to try to remove the first (or any) field. Imagine the mess that would make of a line like `foobar foo bar`. And NEVER use a shell loop like in your 2nd script (which would be incredibly slow and absolutely trash your files given some input file contents) just to manipulate text - UNIX shell is an environment from which to call UNIX tools and the UNIX text manipulation tool is awk so just use that.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

```
awk -F'\t' '$1!=prev{close(out); out=$1".txt"; prev=$1} {sub(/[^\t]+\t/,""); print > out}' file
```

Comment: you are a wonderful human being! I'm looking up everything in the command you typed to better understand what I'm doing. Thank you for helping me!

Comment: You're welcome, feel free to ask questions if you have any after you've done some initial research. Everyone who uses UNIX to manipulate text should buy the book Effective Awk Programming, 4th Edition, by Arnold Robbins.

Answer (score 3):

This one worked for me. Just added a counter to your second solution

`counter=0; cat your_file.txt | while read LINE; do ((counter++)); echo $LINE > "path/to/your/files/$counter.txt"; done`